# Java SMPP API detect disconnection when SMSC has network failure or power failure

Tags: java, smpp

My Java project(client) uses [Java SMPP API](http://smppapi.sourceforge.net/documentation/user-guide/) to connect SMSC. I am doing disconnection testing on the project. When I shutdown SMSC simulator, the client can detect the connection lost, but if I turn off the network on SMSC simulator, the client can't detect disconnection.

Even I check `connection.isBound()` or `connection.getState()`, both indicate the connection is still alive. My suspect is when network failrue or power failure occure, the connection session is still open.

Below is my code establish connection:

```
 connection = new Connection(config.getSmscHostname(), config.getSmscPort(),true /*async=true*/);
 connection.addObserver(this);
 connection.autoAckMessages(true);
 connection.autoAckLink(true);
 connection.bind(config.getBindType(), config.getSystemId(), config.getSecret(), 
 config.getSystemType(), config.getSourceTON(),
                    config.getSourceNPI(), config.getShortcode());
```

I have override the `ConnectionObserver` method `update(Connection source, SMPPPacket packet)`, but it only works when SMSC simulator shutdown clean.

```
    /**
     * Called for all events <b>other</b> than packet reception. This method is
     * called for all events generated by the API framework <i>except </i> that
     * of a packet received. The {@link #packetReceived}method is called in
     * that case. The <code>update</code> method is mostly used for control
     * events, such as signifying the exit of the receiver thread or notifying
     * of error conditions.
     *
     * @param source
     *            the Connection which received the packet.
     * @param event
     *            the SMPP event type.
     * @see ie.omk.smpp.event.SMPPEvent#getType
     */
    @Override
    public void update(Connection source, SMPPEvent event){
        if(event.getType() == SMPPEvent.RECEIVER_EXIT
                && ((ReceiverExitEvent) event).getReason() == ReceiverExitEvent.EXCEPTION) {
            //We have lost the connection to the SMSC. 
            interruptAndTermintateExecution(new SmscException(SmscException.Reason.LOST_CONNECTION, "SMSC is down, lost connection."));
            logger.error("SMSC is down, lost connection...");
//            eaDown.emit("Smsc is down, lost connection");// notifies Health Link
        }
```

Is there anyway to detect it on the client side? Please help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with this API, but, you can attempt to PING or use any other command that can be used to determine what you are looking for with the host through a terminal command.

This can be done programmatically, shown below.

What the process does is....

1. Execute a command through the runtime terminal of your OS
2. Hooks the I/O streams of the executed process
3. Use's those streams to determine if the operation was successful.

Even if Pinging does not come out useful in your case, there are many other command line techniques that can be used to determine if a remote host is available or not, just change the arguments of what you wish to execute, and use its I/O Streams to validate the connection based on its output the same way.

Hope this helps :)

```
if (os.toLowerCase().contains("win")) {
    args = new String[] { "cmd", "/c", "PING" + host };
} else {
    args = new String[] { "bash", "-c", "PING" + host };
}
ProcessBuilder pipeline = new ProcessBuilder(args);
pipeline.redirectError(Redirect.PIPE);
pipeline.redirectInput(Redirect.PIPE);
pipeline.redirectOutput(Redirect.PIPE);
pipeline.start();


//Gets the I/O Streams of the process we just executed
bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pipeline.getInputStream()));
bufferedEReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pipeline.getErrorStream()));
bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(pipeline.getOutputStream()));


//Reading the streams
String line = null;
while (streaming) {
    try {
        if (bufferedReader.ready()) {
            line = bufferedReader.readLine();
            if (line.contains("A SUCCESS MESSAGE")) {
                  //We have our success message, do what you need
            }
            bufferedWriter.flush();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
 }
```